# Perché si dice 'la mano' e non 'il mano'?

Tags: word-usage

Generalmente i sostantivi che terminano con la vocale 'o' sono maschili, il sostantivo 'mano' è una eccezione. Perché 'mano' è considerato un sostantivo femminile?

Comment: Anche *eco* (al singolare)

Comment: E *clima* fa il contrario, per esempio.

Comment: Problema,  dilemma, emblema, anatema, stilema...

Comment: Il coma, l'automa, il cobra... C'è anche il boa (serpente), ma questa parola può essere femminile (la boa, ossia il galleggiante)

Comment: Anche l'uovo è interessante.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Mano deriva dal latino "*manus*, *manus*", sostantivo femminile della IV declinazione.
In italiano la parola è rimasta come "mano" e non "mana" perché quasi tutte le parole latine che hanno desinenza *-us* (che in genere sono della II declinazione) sono passate con la desinenza *-o*.

Comment: "manŭs, manūs", per la precisione, con ablativo "manū"